# YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds giving odd error

Tags: youtube-api

I am getting odd error from youtube  Player API which was working fine few hours ago.

Can anyone provide me solution for that?

```
500 Internal Server Error
Sorry, something went wrong.

A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation.

If you see them, send them this information as text (screenshots frighten them):
    APkpgMUuvG-WqGSx1NgX6ikC3Hug0fm1givbK0ZiHsIQKJ5x6CZVmC8d
    xU9F-VsLT1fQhpkvfx_kPwioGZT6fo-1VY8k_YKPEPXdozPTSv6rzxSS
    -izWw5e0YfQRVKwRwWx4wW7D7fr_R9jbRVn188WqvnwAofxogSquhhkM
    TUZh38X9019w4gbMCu3Ll_qrtEHsYtb3M8e7HIRsjwiSzrSgEzmlNCXB
    UudgKPSvZeDIYIesYNnIcU1G_Ylnazir2vn9LqrdBJyQ2oIxrecKjyr1
    WKdQvWVJyCreViU45xTWsUni5T-DpipWZo_SHFd_xrsjBWTt69B-DaGs
    uM5TtT34mcqJ1taAyUt8oPsatZU6kVEjPu-_zeLTRqho0mq9_l5nzzgd
    kUm2XudQuIS0N3tbFwzgbFFZ4h_JnX5hVAEnEs5qcc9rp-NBCw4fJMxp
    POdLQASYRQuBT-T-cCbqptyvy2tYacSZxfKiVc-Hfgp1mTE0hRZSSOMj
    NXEyj2RwLAyWGe4ZQVXpNJyG25mCciCO7KNMIBmMNGlp5X6sshZRvTZc
    hQLgIn3yr3AsF53UP_3WXONu3vBWEbNzYdl6xVPivAr0rFhOhUHHZb2t
    WCFN5NtXd-MKoKXHPb4scnXqBtkpb4sGteeDty3acvtkQS43y61lGdWe
    BsvSdVAZ2NiKZzZxnkHBtaRirXgdCoNdVYDCe0W4TRiTpaRD3FvqNdJw
    TawuXwz8YRB1-ruv5lq_f_zkB9r-ABqHW9MMR5LFHAV7y5S4mcSzJP2A
    w3PlilAgsVe52yIhdR5qOxvtSzrnNEX7MgS9KRGhTukkSf8awkM4sbFq
    xy4YmGw4maLpqVg6yji7WZcw2v_-sLttb9rJpCxBWhRcd0kO4lmCjcK6
    AUtHRiTOzZUcAIsPpa-aqllAo_-NeDqCPHJYcGZRJtXBGitfLwRtYKZE
    V2mCuQhWeqQ0KdONSXxZsMHwT1qr8gOltCaE-rLz76zu62znURFad3Nr
    n8TTwai_u3JyjxBXNKXG-O5y0UpROOi9wEBibic3Xcg3OwuJfXVRc-Lt
    aCdTcquCYKU0BIth3GOemtYNWM6mQg9SPM9RpxwpvQ-CIDsmfJlt7FZC
    A92YbbuTVtN9Na6q96C-Zkr-mcP9oUDCRsnWPXhjWJP0lBzK6DlkEVFv
    jK772GjGLzLXOqsvPy9qEHbvqxpwqKrZhRSgYkTWsE2HyaJZUgupn2zU
    EVFeJH33BFP_8YGKk_pfg_sqz5jgvFfl4aOe-pSw9Hbfp0maxfLGFiPV
    PZk4n8Qnd0RADJow6TnjmhJlIe_v7d7MMxFIuN9cunMG1RZ7ERlL5Uqm
    2M9yq8mhOy_7EUDX7_eu-rCkN05y1FlFGcD1AQcF6P66AN9dGfhC7o79
    x_sBHvqCB2jntZGnDRYPj6JTJN7Dz4OZ0-lQF42xDAqBRDYdVZ1SJJbw
    B0VYMNuP49Mx4wgmB10iZcVcHzNF7BYw6hPCNF19FkMu6tBn2Kh37xog
    W6wTQbDjMX2rrpbasHHtdzj13mDYQxxc_BKt8SQHs1lCVOjoDnSqPyOg
    TwtD5C9tnkulHUwj9LP2Hix9TxUXQL8xU06UDM3zsDvrr_hBP_L1Jk3X
    sadbwrAkRNMDcbc0pJ5760vbPowC_JUCN5DOAXUFTPm_DmZ_r6QmYW6q
    goT52quJyOLz-4xgm12haRoF3sJFxBbu3KysthkbKIjHjQuV0m_HDStd
    dBTM-_abWKrZVjq_iE66jeVuvrGTxYMCQesejWzl2u8AJulzlGsFJEgy
    y2I_wkc7Ds6MqM06jDoFUB-rgBiGNC-ks090OHNwmX8pnl-ufheiCVNc
    xKqNRQa3t6zT8PrwJtlsxxAQ423Ck4Kbd8rjAQardJk-3QCR8lin27MH
    nplhUSQUyD6z5ipd889XiapPKVNgTv40_MbHIy8lp5gPYGWu4SEwQSRA
    gJjpheNUxlOTn6nCErWDqyToOMNFKsYaBvbdLnSxTX9lvRPMpn25GOCk
    Ba0a9Gr3dc6LvW6yDB_KtUJbvWId0V6hzeLBxZ793OC8GcXW2olV_dI7
    M9AeQ11lQT7hbGxgdszp8aDP8pnlHLi_EhBASRrM4AQabGpW8cgC5wnO
    GeF-8Sqb-ULJjvK3GEaPnfAvl-rT2L8vYTCRpOg6Ndy8_LBZ5Iq0QgzQ
    d1ISqXW_EW1T2NR7E2YI3NJwcwVz5aoz8htwzwcfT0T_Z5wJ1ivSW-Gd
    pk4iU_fGuQ
```

Comment: Same here! Getting 500 error.

Comment: This issue fixed now